# urg node on ros indigo

Tags: hokuyo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and as part of the tutorial, I am trying to install the hokuyo laser driver and have tried all the solutions posted so far but I keep getting the same error message

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-laser-drivers 
E: unable to locate package ros-fuerte-laser-drivers
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-urg-node 
E: unable to locate package ros-hydro-urg-node
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 running on VirtualBox. I have ROS indigo igloo. Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191868/urg-node-on-ros-indigo/) by [hry](https://answers.ros.org/users/20128/hry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you're using ROS Indigo, you should install the package with "indigo" in the package name:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-laser-drivers
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-urg-node
```

(note that I've replaced "fuerte" and "hydro" in the package name with "indigo").

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hry](https://answers.ros.org/users/20128/hry/) on 2014-09-04**:
Thank you ahendrix, darn!!!, why didn't I think of this solution earlier